# How to addHeaderView in ListView

Tags: android, listview, classcastexception

I am using listView with cursorAdapter. What I need is to add some layout to the top of this listView.

```
mListView.addHeaderView(mLayout);
```

on android 4.4 and above it work great, but for example on 4.0 - i got en error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

is there any other way to do this or how an I fix this?

thanks!

Comment: Can you share snipper code?

Comment: @Dekra, what do you mean by snipper ?

Comment: Snippet code about the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First inflate your layout with:

```
View mHeader = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

and add it to your listview with:

```
yourListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);
```

Edit: We need more information to solve your problem completely we need to see your code but if i guess you can solve it with:

```
AbsListView absListView = (AbsListView) viewGroup;
```